# Заголовок выходит за границы типа ленточки

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, много где видел, к сожалению, вспомнить не могу где именно, попробую объяснить, есть заголовок определенного блока или меню, и его фон типа ленточки выходит за границы блока и обхватывает его, как такое сделать? Рад бы увидеть примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внутри блока сделать эти ленточки, например так:

```
< div >
< img class="left" src="lentochka_left.png" >
< img class="right" src="lentochka_right.png" >
< /div >
```

И сделать div'у position: relative, картинкам position: absolute.
С помощью left и right задать положение, отрицательное значение выведет элементы за пределы div